# RegEx Lookahead (Optional)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a Reddit bot and he responds whenever a comment matches a pattern. Currently he responds a little bit too much and I want to cut that down by making the pattern more precise.

```
(\n|^)define:? (-ignore|"?([^\n,.!?#&_:;"\\(){}<>[\]]+))(, ?((pro)?noun|(ad)?verb(-(in)?transitive)?|adjective|abbreviation|(preposi|conjunc|interjec)tion))?
```

That's the pattern. The bot matches the following:
`define[:] ["]word/phrase["][, part of speech]` but not everyone knows about the bot and will type things like
`"define this because that"` and the pattern matches all of it. When I added the following to the end of the 4th capturing group, it will only match strings that have the words `"and"`, `"please"` or `"because"` in them.

```
(?= (and|please|because))
```

But when testing at [RegExr](http://regexr.com), I found that making the addition optional, it would cause strings like `"define this because that"` to match all in the 4th capture group.

How can I make the addition optional but required when those words are in a string?

If it makes any difference, the bot is written in python.

Comment: I guess by "optional but required" you mean you want to see them in the match. Did you trying just adding a question mark like `(?= (and|please|because)?)`? Or maybe even `(?=(?: (and|please|because))?)`?

Comment: What I meant by optional but required is that if and,because, or please aren't in the string, the pattern will act as if the addition wasn't added. If they are in the string, it will end without including them in the result.

Comment: Could you please check https://regex101.com/r/vK8cG5/1 and let know what is wrong, what you want to match? The problem is still unclear to me, it would be great if you added some more specific examples of input and required output to the question.

Comment: @stribizhev I said adding that to the 4th capture group. See https://regex101.com/r/oF4kE5/1

Comment: @Spedwards I think your question can be made clearer with a series of different cases, and how the regex should handle each of these cases, and where the current one you have is currently failing.